# JVM parameters for application server

Tags: websphere

Recently, we upgraded CLM 5.0.2 to CLM 6.0.5 (Distributed Topology) and along with that we have WAS 9.0.0.7 and DB2. We are using applicaitons like CCM, RM, QM, DM, Rational Insight and each servers having 128GB of RAM. While configuring WAS JVM properties -Xmx -Xms we configured with 64g in each applications, for effective change we need to Stop and Start the WAS. After stopping the WAS we were not able to Start the WAS again and we checked the log file and it mentioned 64g is too large. As of now we configured JVM properties with 24g in each applications.

My question is, How to utilise that 128GB RAM? What will be the reason for the log message "64g is too large"? Compare to 128GB RAM, -Xmx24g -Xmx24g is very low and also accessing applications will be low.

Any Solution...

Comment: What is the full, verbatim error message?

Answer (score 1):

In a 64-bit system, object references can be 8-byte long if Compressed Oops is turned off. That means that every reference to an object is 8 bytes. However modern JVMs enable Compressed Oops by default, thus reducing object reference size to 4 bytes. It is at the cost of max allowed heap space. Max allowed heap space is 32G when Compressed Oops is enabled.

You can disable this by using -XX:-UseCompressedOops option.